# Drag and Drop GridView with Page

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-viewpager, android-gridview

Hi aside from [PagedDragDropGrid](https://github.com/mrKlar/PagedDragDropGrid) is there another way to implement DragandDrop in gridview with viewpager? PagedDragDropGrid don't have a onItemClick listener and when I drag and drop, It only switch the views but not the object. Can anyone help me with my problem? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This is [DragDrop_ChangeSize_Grid](https://github.com/henry434343/Android_DragDrop_ChangeSize_Grid) UI on Android.
You can click item to switch item color and long click item to edit mode

```
In edit mode:  
    1. Resize item  
    2. Move item  
    3. Delete item
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reference. Is there a way to implement that along with viewpager?

Comment: this project is build in basefragment so that you just put each fragment to your viewpager

Comment: thanks for the info I'll try it first and then I'll update you.. Thanks! much appreciated.

Comment: btw what I mean is can I drag and drop a item to the other page?